# Lightweight Portable Editors

Tags: windows, editor

I'm looking for **free** lightweight editors that can be run directly from a flash drive, without any install.

I would like editors that support as many languages as possible, I have notepad++ but I don't particularly care for it.

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm looking for editors for windows.

Comment: Thanks for the spelling, apparently Chrome doesn't spell check the title field. :(

Comment: You should clarify whether you are talking about multiple natural languages, or programming languages.

Comment: Probably, It should be a community-wiki post.

Comment: From your title, one expects "looking for portable Eclipse". vim has a bunch of up-votes, but I'd hardly call it an IDE. Maybe your title should include "editors" as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [Portable GVim](http://portablegvim.sourceforge.net/) makes the goodness of vim portable.

It's got syntax highlighting for more languages that I can name and all kinds of vim goodness.

Comment: I prefer making [plain old vim portable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636691/2587343), as it takes one line in config.

Answer (score 8):

I swear by [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) ,which isn't exactly a code editor, but it has support for syntax highlighting for many text formats, and they just don't come any lighterweight or more portable.

Comment: I followed your link OOC. It appears to be roughly 300K uncompressed. That is indeed pretty darn lightweight these days. I did the same with a small distro of NT emacs, and it came to a bit less than 50Meg

Answer (score 4):

I like [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), and there's also [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

Answer (score 4):

[JEdit](http://jedit.org/) is a fairly lightweight text editor with all the trimmings.  You can dowload loads of plugins.  It's written in java, too, so you can use it cross-platform.

Portable version [here](http://portableapps.com/node/11617), thanks to [@redsquare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440/redsquare) for the link.

Comment: @Wayne:  You're quite right!  
@redsquare:  Thanks for the link!

Comment: redsquare: Nice one, quite right, I've changed my vote to Up.

Answer (score 2):

SciTE @ http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html

The list of supported languages in very impressive.  Includes most features of modern editors - syntax highlighting, code folding, unlimited undo/redo, find/replace with regular expressions, auto indent, etc.  It is rock solid - never had it crash or bug out in the 5+ years I've been using it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Programmer’s Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) , which does have a portable version. I wouldn't say however that is better that notepad++. In fact, I don't think you can get any better than this in the free world.

Comment: I just don't care for notepad++, most of the people I have talked don't like it for my languages either. PHP/Python!

Comment: Fair comment, there are plugins available for it that improve notepad++ however I have yet to try them out.

Comment: Talking of Python, Programmer's Notepad has a Python extension (PyPN) that allows scripting of PN using Python.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)?

Comment: Ahhhhh, I tried to add emacs but 150MB ?????????  That blows WAY over my 1GB Budget for this project.

Comment: Err...I don't understand. 150MB < 1GB, right? Or do you already have 900MB of other stuff?

Answer (score 1):

[Emacs for Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/ntemacs.html) should do it. It has been known to run off of CD before. A flash drive should be a cinch compared to that.

To check, I just went and downloaded the latest "bin" version from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/. It unpacked to a 45MB directory. If you can't spare that much space, you are in trouble.

For comparison's sake (and for those of you who prefer another editor) I went through the downloads for everything mentioned here to find the (uncompressed) sizes.

- Emacs (without Lisp or code sources) - 45MB
- GVim - 22MB
- Notepad2 - 300MB
- JEdit - 15MB
- Scintilla (self-uncompressing version) - 500K
- Programmer's Notepad - 6MB
- Notepad++ Portable - 9MB

If it were me, I'd try them out in order of editor preference, (from my most to least favorite), then stop with the first one that fits in the space required.

Comment: You have probably accidentaly made a mistake about the size of Notepad2. It is not 300Mb. Size varies with version, but it is more in the range of 300-500kb.

Answer (score 0):

The choice on portableapps.com is a bit limited: http://portableapps.com/apps/development

There's NVU which looks to be more full-on than notepad++ but personally notepad++ hooked into winscp is my tool of choice for web development at the moment. Anything else gets a bit clunky and unresponsive.

Not sure if it will work from a flash drive but [Intype](http://intype.info/home/index.php) looks promising aswell.

Answer (score 0):

PSPad is decent, also if you don't mind me asking, what is it exactly you dislike about notepad++, and you do realize with a portable IDE you need the whole works to go with it or you are just carrying around a bloated editor (not matter how lightweight the IDE).

[Here](http://www.portablefreeware.com/all.php) is a good site to find all sorts of portable software and [here](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?sc=14&p=1) is the editors page.

Comment: This is actually for a project I'm working on I have added the majority of the suggested editors, and I don't care for notepad++ likely because my normal IDE (ZEND) spoils me ALOT.  I don't care for the code-completion, which is my BIGGEST complaint.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're really looking for is a text editor, not an IDE. I have long been a fan of [Crimson Editor](http://crimsoneditor.com/). There are many great editors for Windows, but I found Crimson Editor to have a really nice interface, and every feature I could want in my text editor, so I've always come back to it for any time I'm not using vim/gvim.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at portableapps.com the only other app I can see that might work for you is [Abiword](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/abiword_portable) but that's more of a word processor than just a text editor, but might be worth checking out anyway.

Then there is Akelpad, which seems very lightweight: http://akelpad.sourceforge.net/en/index.php

**Edit:** This is a relevant and researched answer.  Can whoever rated this down please explain why in the comments?  That would be good netiquette and manners, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -2):

Although not free, [ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) has always been a favorite light weight editor for me.  I think I definitely got my money's worth with that one.