# Is there a way to install portable Vim ?

Tags: vim, installation

Is there a way to install `vim` without running the `.exe` executable, since the computer does not have installation privilege.

Comment: Maybe this one help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600009/making-vim-portable

Answer (score 0):

I have no Windows to test, but a up-to-date version of Vim can  be downloaded here:

https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

Download a zip and unpack it to a custom location. Also read the README.md of the project.

Without installing there are no "Edit with Vim" menu entries.